# What is inaccessible in a world without mobs?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I started playing a couple of days ago in split-screen. Since I am horrible with controllers (we are playing on an Xbox One), I asked to make a world without mobs.

After a bit we realized that we won't have cows, so no leather, so no book production, no bookshelves, and lower grade enchantments.

What are all the things that are not available in a world without mobs?

Note: I have since found several cave spider spawners and a skeleton spawner, but no other type, and there is no plan to turn mob spawning back on.

Comment: Note that fishing can give you leather. Most other things can be found in very, very limited quantities in chests as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rotten Flesh, bones, meat of all kinds, Phantom membranes, Blaze Rod, Ghast Tear, Ender Pearls, Magma Cream, Spider Eye, Leather and Rabbit Hide, Mob Heads, String, Rabbit's Foot, Slime Balls, Gunpowder, any type of Villager-exclusive trade such as Bottles of Enchanting, and others that I can't think of at the moment.

Leather can be found in village tannery house chests (Unless you disabled structures), and someone else mentioned it can be found through fishing. Rotten Flesh and Bones can be found in chests, Rotten Flesh in Underwater Ruins and I believe Desert Temples as well as by fishing, and Bones in Desert Temples. Spider Eyes can be found in Desert Temples sometimes. Slime Balls can't be found in chests, so you have to rely on taking apart the redstone in Jungle Temples for sticky pistons. Raw Beef can be found in a villager butcher house chest, I don't know if other types of meat can though. Potion Brewing Stands can be found in villages as the Cleric workstation, but there isn't much use to them as most useful potions require mob drops. String can be found in Mineshafts and Abandoned Villages through cobwebs in rather plentiful amounts, I've found around half a stack of string at least in one wander through a Mineshaft. Gunpowder can be obtained in Dungeons, Desert Temples, and Village Chests, and there is TNT in the Desert Temple trap if that's why you want gunpowder.

You won't be able to beat the game unfortunately, but you might be able to find Ender Pearls in Stronghold Chests. Hope this was of help, I'll edit if anything else pops up.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable mob spawning but switch the difficulty to Peaceful so that no hostile mobs spawn but passive ones do. Just be wary of hostile wolves (wolves that have been attacked) as they are still hostile.

Comment: I believe hostile wolves or any mobs that become hostile (Iron Golems, Polar Bears, etc.) won't do any damage to the player.

Answer (score 3):

Although I cannot bring up a full list right now, I did want to mention something that I think would be quite significant if you're planning on beating the game on that world with no mobs; the only way to obtain blaze rods are via blazes, and so if no blazes spawn, you wouldn't be getting any blaze rods needed to craft Eyes of Enders (unless monster spawner blocks aren't effected by the "Disable mob spawns" gamerule, however I believe that it would be unlikely to be the case).

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the downvote, since although this wasn't a complete list of items, I still provided information about one of the more significant items in a Minecraft run that you cannot obtain without the help of mob spawns. If there is something that I can do to help improve my current answer, I would like to know.

Comment: I have not downvoted, as I have no idea what you are talking about, but I can tell you that to my displeasure, we found that spawner blocks are not affected: we found 2 Poisonous Spider and at least a Skeleton Spawner blocks in close proximity of each other

Comment: Disabling mob spawning should disable spawners